# Magento 2: How redirect from controller to another controller to POST method?

Tags: magento2, redirect, store-view

I am trying to redirect the customer when their store view is not correct. When I redirect the _request method it is GET and I need it to be POST

```
  if ($currentStore !== $customerStore) {
       $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
       $url = $this->_url->setScope($customerStore)->getUrl('customer/account/loginPost', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
       $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
       $resultRedirect->setUrl($url);
       return $resultRedirect;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use like this.

```
$this->_redirect('customer/account/loginPost');
```

It will redirect there.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241547/70343

```
$param = ['param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2'];
    $resultRedirect->setPath('frontname/path/controllername', ['params' => $params]);
```

Failing that you could look into a curl request. With curl you can post to a url with params.